# Depending on the value of $r^2$, how many solution can the following simultaneous equations have? $x^2+y^2=r^2$; $|x|+|y|=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Depending on the value of $r^2$, how many solution can the following simultaneous equations have? 
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
$$|x|+|y|=2$$

Can you give me a step by step answer to this question?

Comment: Draw a picture for a few values of $r$. The second equality looks like a diamond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|x|+|y|=2$ is a square with the corners at the points:
${(2,0),\ (0,2),\ (-2,0),\ (0,-2)}$

(look at this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%7C+%2B+%7Cy%7C+%3D+2)

Now try graphing these circles yourself:

$x^2+y^2=(\sqrt2)^2  \ \ \ \ $(a circle centered at (0,0) of radius $\sqrt2$)

$x^2+y^2=2^2  \ \ \ \ $(a circle centered at (0,0) of radius $2$)

Both of the above circles will intersect the square at four distinct points.

Now if you take any $r\in(\sqrt2,2)\ \ $ (all the values in between $\sqrt2$ and $2$, but not including $\sqrt2$ and $2$), then $that$ circle will intersect the square at eight distinct points.

Answer (score 2):

Graphic of $|x|+|y|=2$ is square with the centre in point (0,0)and  diagonal 4. $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is circle with radius r and  centre in (0,0).  Try to draw circles with different radius and you will see how many solutions system have .